How to access ubuntu file system from grub command line
After I enter the grub environment while in recovery mode for Virtual Box, I need to delete files, but I can't seem to access the file system. How do I access the Ubuntu file system from grub?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why do you assume that you have the capability to "access the Ubuntu file system from grub" to "delete files"? Did you try the help command from the grub shell?

Maybe take a couple steps backwards and tell us what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps we can suggest a better way to do this. I would guess the issue is that the OS filesystem is not mounted in grub, or it is entirely inaccessible, if you're dealing with an encrypted partition. But, knowing what your end goals are will help us better help you.
